# PHP create cookies on different domains on same server (cURL)

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm creating a multilingual web site and after user logs in I need to create cookies across all domains (on same server):

```
example.com
example.de
example.it
```

I know for this solution - http://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains (calling a **.php file** from inside **img** attribute) but is there any pure PHP solution ?

I'm trying to work out **cURL** solution but it doesn't work:

```
$url = "http://www.example.de/createcookie.php?value=hashvar";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($curl);
```

After user login it needs to create cookie on current domain and then calls (via cURL) createcookie.php file that creates cookies on other domains.

Is something like this possible via **cURL** or some other PHP function like **get_file_contents** ?

All domains is placed on same server.

Comment: not possible. site A cannot create cookies for site B on a user's browser, nor will site B's cookies be available via requests to site A. You can do all the curling you want, but those requests are going to originate from your server, and there will be NO way for you to set those cookies on the user's browser, because they're for 'foreign' domains. You will have to physically redirect the user to your other domains. that could be as simple as a chained 301 redirect across all of your domains, or have the browser issue ajax requests to your other domains.

Comment: Ajax request for calling **example.de/createcookie.php?value=hash** could work ?

Comment: you'd have to output `<script src="foo.it/whatever.php">` and have one of those for every one of your domains,a nd then hope that the user has JS enabled.

Comment: It's something like using img tags. Thanks, maybe the redirect is the solution for this ;)

Comment: yeah, images would be easier. that might actually be better. if you offer links to change languages, then you could use the `<img src="http://example.it/italian_icon.php" />` to both set the cookie and serve up the italian flag icon for the "change to italian" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *pure php* solution to this. You can not set a cookie for another domain than the one you are serving your response from. `Curl` and `get_file_contents` do not interact with the user's browser. Setting a cookie is performed by the browser which handles your server response.

However, instead of serving an image (or other file type) from the other two domains (*called third party domains*), you can also redirect through all those domains and set a cookie before every subsequent redirect (using `header("Location: url");`)

I.e. after login on example.com, you redirect to:

- example.it/your_script.php. The file you redirect to sets the cookie and without returning any html redirects to
- example.de/your_script.php. Again, you set a cookie and redirect again to
- example.com/login_destination.php

This however introduces a higher load time than using non-blocking third party objects in your html.

Comment: Another design could be:

have example.com as the main server that handles logins and saves the "master cookie".
When a user visits example.it without that cookie, forward to example.com, which forwards back to example.it with the cookie in a get paremeter - or information that such cookie could not be found.

Comment: Redirection is maybe the solution here. About load time it's only one time when user logs in from example.com, example.de or example.it and it redirect to other language domains. After that it reads cookie from current selected language (domain). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A solution I have used in the past was to create a "session_access" or "cookie_access" table in a database which all sites can access to see if a session/cookie may be created without the need for another login.

Eg...

- Site A is used to login
- PHP creates a record on a "cookie_access" table in MySQL with cookie
  ID.
- User jumps to Site B (via a link or forward with ID passed)
- PHP reads "cookie_access" table for active session based on cookie ID from Site A, if exists, site automatically logs the user in and sets up the new cookie for Site B.

Comment: Implied requirement is to set cookies so user does have it if he visits other domain without a link from the domain he logged in from